# getting "FATAL: Couldn’t find any executable in /root/apache-maven-3.5.3" with Jenkins version 2.107.3. I am CentOS

Tags: jenkins

getting "FATAL: Couldn’t find any executable in /root/apache-maven-3.5.3" with Jenkins version 2.107.3. I am CentOS.

Added paths of Java and Maven in .bash_profile

> git rev-list --no-walk 0caf6111d5ef4679bf818f99fa448a525566ee69 # timeout=10
>   FATAL: Couldn’t find any executable in /root/apache-maven-3.5.3
>   Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Have you configured the path in `Global Tool Configuration` ? If this is not running in a `docker` container, it might be easier to just configure it from there and check the `Install Automatically`.

Comment: Yes I configured the path in "Global Tool Configuration" and its not running from docker... I even gave 777 to Maven folder.. not sure why it does not recognize.

Comment: What user is Jenkins running as?

Comment: I created an user called "admin"

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments under the OP this is definitely a permission issue.

1. You cannot expect to put something in the `/root` path and be able to access it with a user other than `root`. This will most likely fail, because the permissions which are used for home directories, allow only the `root` **user** to `read`, `write` and `execute` things in that path.
2. CentOS has `SELinux enforce` by default and it provides additional security layer which will also prevent users from reading and/or writing to certain paths on the system. So you could actually have the "correct" permissions set for a path, but the user that's trying to read/write something there could still not be able to do it.

In general, you should be running `Jenkins` server and agents under a dedicated user and group - i.e `jenkins` user and group. This will allow you to create a path like `/jenkins/` which is owned by the `jenkins` user & group. Then set that as the path where `Jenkins` installs it's tools.

Comment: Thank you so much for the inputs.. Issue is resolved. Here is how I resolved it. 1. chmod 0755 /root     2.chmod -R 0755 /root/apache-maven-3.5.3